# Dynamic cell access

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

My question may seem quite simple but I haven't found the answer yet.

In excel, I would like to access a cell with a dynamic row number.

Example 1 : cell A(1+2)
Example 2 : cell B(ROW(A1)*10)

What is the syntax  for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you specify? You would like to access a cell from VBA, formula...?

Comment: You can also use the OFFSET formula in a similar context.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the [INDIRECT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) function:

```
=INDIRECT("A" & (1+2))
=INDIRECT("B" & ROW(A1)*10)
```

Comment: I tried this `=INDIRECT("F" & ROW()*G2)` to achieve Current Row of F column * G2.. But no luck

Answer (score 1):

If by 
cell B(ROW(A1)*10)
you meant if A1 was 3 then return the value in B30 ,ie B(3*10)

then you want
=INDIRECT("B" &A1*10)

=INDIRECT("B" & ROW(A1)*10)
will always return cell B10
as ROW(A1) always =1