# Function ="C+ number specified in cell A1) automation

Tags: excel, google-sheets

In a Google Sheet, I would like to enter a number in a cell and have certain functions in that sheet use that number.

So if cell "A1" has the value 2 assigned to it I want a function to use =C+(the value in cell A1), which is 2. So the function displays the value of C2. When changing the number in cell A1 to 5, my function should change to C5 as well . Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be the same as Excel. I tested it.

```
=INDIRECT("C" & VALUE(A1))
```

or

```
=INDIRECT("C"&A1) which is simpler (thanks Nirk)
```

Possible duplicate: [Dynamic cell access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515250/dynamic-cell-access)

Comment: Do you need VALUE?  What about just "C"&A1 or "C"&T(A1)

Comment: @Nirk You are right. VALUE is not needed. I modify my answer.